# Manage TcpClient connection

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I have a device(step motor) connected to my PC via `TCP`. a response to a message sent to the device can return after a number of seconds (usually 3 to 15 seconds).
To communicate with the device and after a lot of reading I came up with the following `class`:

```
public class TcpUtil : IDisposable
{
    public event Action<TcpResponse> OnTcpMessage;

    private int _port;
    private string _ip;

    private TcpClient _client;
    private NetworkStream _stream;

    public TcpUtil(string ip, int port)
    {
        _ip = ip;
        _port = port;

        _client = new TcpClient();

        //connect with timeout
        var connectResult = _client.BeginConnect(ip, port, null, null);

        var success = connectResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(3000);
        if (!success)
        {
            throw new Exception("Connection timeout at " + ip);
        }

        // _stream is used for the duration of the object and cannot be used in a using block
        _stream = _client.GetStream();

        //start listening to incoming messages
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Listen(_client));
    }

    private void Listen(TcpClient clientToUse)
    {
        while (clientToUse.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = _stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead)
                    .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");

                if (OnTcpMessage != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response))
                {
                    var message = new TcpResponse(response, _ip);

                    OnTcpMessage(message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (_client.Connected)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Listener error: " + ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void SendCommand(string command)
    {
        //device requirement - add a newline at the end of a message
        if (!command.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
            command = command + Environment.NewLine;

        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
        _stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_client != null)
            {
                _stream.Dispose();
                _client.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems with the code above:

- Sometimes results are concatenated and not read one by one (this is really inconsistent)
- I could not find a reliable way to associate a sent message with it's response

How can I improve the above code in order for it to solve these problems?

Comment: In a real time system like you have adding a 3 second wait will causes issues.  Any timeouts should be handled asynchronously.  You need to Network layers to make the code work properly.  A top level application layer and a bottom layer TCP transport layer.  With stepping motors you may want to send multiple steps without waiting for a response if the speed of the motor is significantly off the required frequency.  Usually this is done when starting the motor.

Comment: Take a look a following webpage.  The code uses Sockets but the sockets can be replaced with any class that inherits the socket like tcp https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the 3 second wait is the only way I found to create a connection timeout. It only happens once when trying to connect.

Comment: How are your string's delimited? the NetworkStream (and TCP) in general, does not guarantee that upon completion of the `Read()` call that a complete message, or only a single message, will be received. If your responses are always newline-delimited, wrap your stream with a reader class and perform a `ReadLine()` instead.

Comment: Regarding your second question do all commands generate responses, and are incoming messages always a response to a command?

Comment: @nicholas my strings are followed by a `new line` (ascii 10). I'll try adding the `StreamReader`...

Comment: @nicholas is regards to my second question the answer is yes

Answer (score 0):

Add a `StreamReader` object to your class, and a message queue:

```
private StreamReader _reader;
private ConcurrentQueue<string> _sentCommands;
```

Initialize the variables as follows:

```
_stream = _client.GetStream();
_reader = new StreamReader(_stream, Encoding.ASCII);
_sentCommands = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
```

In your `SendMessage` message, keep track of each message you sent:

```
_sentCommands.Enqueue(command);

var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
_stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
```

Then when receiving messages, dequeue, and you will have a command / response pair:

```
try
{
    var response = _reader.ReadLine();
    string command;

    var result = _sentCommands.TryDequeue(out command);

    if (OnTcpMessage != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response))
    {
        // Do something here to take advantage of the command variable
    }
}
//... Rest of code here
```